# Weird crashes in C++ Project on thread.join()

Tags: c++, multithreading

i have written a chess engine which plays at a high level. Unfortunately we are known for multiple engine crashes. There are a few people trying to figure out the reason for those crashes. The code can be found [here](https://github.com/Luecx/Koivisto). We tracked all crashes we encountered down to one file which deals with all the input/output from/to the user. [uci.cpp](https://github.com/Luecx/Koivisto/blob/master/src_files/uci.cpp) is the file.

The job of `uci.cpp/h` is to implement the universal chess protocol (`uci`). For that purpose we have some global `Board` object which represents a position. To be able to receive a `stop` command while the engine searches a specific position, we brought the search into its own thread. We use `thread.joinable()` to check if a search is still running and `searchThread.join()` before we start a new search to make sure we do not have multiple searches running.

Someone has sent us the list of crashes he was able to provoke on his machine:

```
1a) general protection fault on libstdc++.so.6.0.28, thread::join crash
1b) segfault on libpthread-2.31.so (replace 2.31 by your libc version), also thread::join crash
2a) trap stack segment on the binary itself, delete board crash
2b) segfault on the binary itself, delete board crash
```

---

## Error type 1/2: thread.join()

The first 2 crash types are both related to calling `searchThread.join()` although we check if its joinable.

```cpp
void uci_stop() {
    search_stop();
    if (searchThread.joinable()) {
        searchThread.join();
    }
}
```

What are reasons that could `.join()` to fail?
We analysed our code a while ago and were not able to find any memory leaks. As far as we know, all data that is allocated within the searchThread will also get deleted.

---

## Error type 3/4: delete board;

We use a global pointer for the board and in very rare instances, deleting that pointer will fail.
I found a potential solution which will statically allocate the board object globally which means I wouldnt havent to use `new` and `delete` anymore.

```cpp
// old:
Board*      board;

// new:
Board       board{""};
```

We think that this solves the problem and is not the main part of this question although we are still curious why `delete board` could fail in some instances.

All crashes have only occured in roughly 2% of all games. With a game taking about 60 moves, thread.join() fails about 1 in 1000 times.

Comment: That's quite vague still. There could be a use-after-free for `searchThread.join()` and a double-delete for `delete board`. Very hard to tell without more information. You could try using some tools to detect issues, like valgrind or the AddressSanitizer. Finally, you can try recording an execution including crash with Mozilla's RR.

Comment: What is a use-after-free? I assume `join` will wait for the searchThread to finish?

Comment: The reason I am unable to analyse this issue properly is because it happens very rarely. Running games within valgrind does not seem to work the way we would like to since games are running using `cutechess-cli`

Comment: and provoking them manually is ever harder. It was very hard work to find the places it crashes. We have used valgrind to detect memory leaks but didnt find those.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: A use-after-free is literally the use of an object after it has been freed. In your case, `searchThread` is a global (which usually don't suffer from use-after-free) but it maintains a thread object. If someone assigns to `searchThread` concurrently to the `searchThread.join()`, that would be a data race which might result in something like a use-after-free.

Comment: oh so only a single thread assigns a new thread to the searchThread and that is the same thread which calls `.join()`

Comment: `joinable()` does not tell you whether a thread is still running. It returns `true` if the thread was not default-constructed, was not `detached()`ed, and has not been `join()`ed. If the thread is still running, `join()` will block until the thread finishes.

Comment: @AlanBirtles As i said, its almost impossible to find a minimal reproducible example. The issue occurs with the entire project and very rarely. Provoking it takes many minutes up to half an hour.

Comment: @PeteBecker If a thread is joinable, we consider it to have been used or is still being used with a search

Comment: @FinnEggers — your question says that you use `joinable()` to “check if a search is still running”. It does not do that. I told you what it’s specification is. If you fire off a search and you don’t detach the thread, the thread object is joinable, regardless of whether the search is still running.

Comment: Yes sorry, that wasnt well formulated by me. Before any search, we need to make sure there is no search running, so we join the thread if its joinable

Comment: The error doesn't even have to be related to `join`. A stray pointer can easily corrupt structures which causes UB. I would check for out of bound writes, which are not always detectable by tools like valgrind. If the search loop crashes, it means that the problem already happened long before.

Comment: There is a good chance you are seeing the impact of Undefined Behavior that occurs elsewhere in your code. "Random" and sporadic crashes, as well as crashes in seemingly impossible places are both strong clues that you this is the case. Edit : Since this is a threaded application, a slight error in synchronization anywhere in the program could easily lead to a race condition and this kind of problem.

Comment: Join:((   Trying to build non-trivial multithreaded apps with join() is just...nasty.  Trying to test if a thread has'finished' by polling anything is a design fail, even if you do not misuse join/joinable horrors.  Designs like this are almost driven by the deficient pthreads library and truly dire 'intro to threads' sites:((   Continual create/terminate/join results in poorly-performing and near-undebuggable apps.  Consider redesign with app-lifetime threads and/or pools.

Comment: how would one go about solving this problem? What tools are best used for this?

Comment: @FinnEggers If the problem is caused by UB, then this is one of the hardest types of bugs to solve. You can try to use static analysis tools, memory analysis tool (like valgrind) and code sanitizers to try to detect any UB that may be the cause, but they aren't guaranteed to find it, specially if the cause is a race condition. Multithreading is very hard to get 100% right, and if you don't get it 100% right you get these kinds of problems. Edit : I agree with Martin James and it may be worth considering redesigning your approach.

Comment: Alright thanks! So I will look into data race issues :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: 'What tools are best used for this?' Top level restructure, messaging, producer-consumer queues, app-lifetime tbreads, thread pools and no join anywhere.

Comment: I am considering attempting  a canonical answer to this.  'Threads intro' sites, pthreads and join() would not come out well:)

Comment: A quick glance through your repository doesn't reveal a hint of thread synchronization. While that's not impossible with careful design, it is very rare.